# vgaswitcheroo has a blank switch file inside and its locked

Tags: permissions, vgaswitcheroo

I'm tying to use Hybrid Graphics and there is a step that I can't do:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

It says

```
cat: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: Operation not permitted
```

I've found that the "switch" file has 0 bytes and it should have this:

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

If I try to edit, I get permission problems. I can't rename and also cant delete or cant create another file inside the folder. (as root)

Who to fix this?

Some says "debugfs" will change permissions back every reboot